# Design pattern to apply Customization Filter

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template-meta-programming

Lets say there is a class Foo, which defines its behavior using F1, F2, F3 functions. There are few clients which extends behavior of Foo and customizes it as per their need.

For such scenario its straight forward to implement it as

```
class Foo
{
public:
virtual void F1() { // default behavior }
virtual void F2() { // default behavior }
virtual void F3() { // default behavior }
}


class CustomFoo1 : public Foo
{
public:
void F1() override { // customized behavior }
void F11() { // CustomFoo1's own methods }
}


class CustomFoo2 : public Foo
{
public:
void F1() override { // customized behavior }
void F21() { // CustomFoo2's own methods }
void F22() { // CustomFoo2's own methods }
}
```

Right? But this is possible only if my library exposes Class Foo for other clients to create CustomFoo1 and CustomFoo2. I don't want to expose my concrete implementation, rather I would use interface which others can use. So I can change my implementation as:

```
interface IFoo // Public interface
{
    public:
    virtual void F1() = 0;
    virtual void F2() = 0;
    virtual void F3() = 0;
}

Class Foo : public IFoo // Internal to library
{
    public:
    virtual void F1() override { // default behavior }
    virtual void F2() override { // default behavior }
    virtual void F3() override { // default behavior }
}

static IFoo* CreateFoo() { return new Foo(); }

class CustomFoo1 : public IFoo
{
public: 
   void F1() override { // Custom Behavior }
   void F2() override { pFoo->F2(); // Need default so delegate call to default implementation }
   void F3() override { pFoo->F3(); // Need default so delegate call to default implementation }    
   void F11() { // personal own implementation }
private:
IFoo* pFoo;
}
```

Same will be done for CustomFoo2.

But here if you see, I am able to hide my concrete implementation behind interface, but that caused my clients to actually implement whole interface and delegate call to default implementation from library if customized classes do not want to override anything from default behavior. So I don't think this is good solution either.

This makes me think about next possible solution. If you take close look at it, clients of library are really looking for customizing only F1(). 
So I am declaring another interface say IFooCustomizePolicy

```
interface IFooCustomizePolicy
{
public:
virtual void F1Customized() = 0;
}
```

I will modify IFoo as:

```
interface IFoo // Public interface
{
    public:
    virtual void F1() = 0;
    virtual void F2() = 0;
    virtual void F3() = 0;
    virtual void RegisterCustomizationPolicy(IFooCustomizePolicy* pPolicy) = 0;
}
```

Update Concrete implementation as :

```
Class Foo : public IFoo // Internal to library
{
    public:
    void F1() override 
    { 
          if( pPolicy != nullptr ) 
             pPolicy->F1Customized();
          else
             // default behavior 
    }
    void F2() override { // default behavior }
    void F3() override { // default behavior }
    void RegisterCustomizationPolicy(IFooCustomizePolicy* pPolicy) override 
      { this->pPolicy = pPolicy; }

private:
IFooCustomizePolicy* pPolicy; 
}
```

And other clients will be modified as:

```
class CustomFoo1 : public IFooCustomizePolicy
{
public:
   void F1Customized() override { // customized behavior }
   void F11() { //CustomFoo1's own methods  }
}
```

Now if you see, with this approach I am able to hide my concrete class, yet able to provide default behavior to client along with way to customize it.

Now lets say, requirements changes and new client comes and asks for new method to be customizable. In this case, I would have to update Policy Interface, which is okay, that's acceptable. But along with that what I would need to do is to update Foo's corresponding method to respect policy and add below logic to methods everytime they are added to policy.

```
if( policy present ) then call policy customized method 
else continue with default behavior
```

If you see here, what I really want is kind of filter, If my object have policy then filter should call policy method and should not continue with default implementation. But I am not sure what pattern to apply and how?

Comment: I feel a bridge design pattern can work well here so that the interface can be separated from the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're leaning towards is "composition instead of inheritance" - which is often a good thing.

The pain you're running into with the default methods is because you've not taken it far enough.

You can avoid putting default methods in `Foo` by **always** having an `F1Policy`, but initially setting it to a default policy.

```
class Foo : public IFoo {
public:
  void F1() override { 
     f1Policy->f();
  }
  void F2() override {
     f2Policy->f();
  }

  void setF1Policy( const shared_ptr<F1Policy> &newPolicy ) {
    f1Policy = newPolicy;
  }

protected:
  shared_ptr<F1Policy> f1Policy(new DefaultF1Policy);
  shared_ptr<F2Policy> f2Policy(new DefaultF2Policy);
  ...
};
```

Now usually you wont store state in the default policy - which will let you reuse an instance. So the construction will become something like:

```
shared_ptr<F1Policy> f1Policy = DefaultF1Policy.instance;
shared_ptr<F1Policy> f2Policy = DefaultF2Policy.instance;
```

The next thing you might run into is that the policies need their `f()` to be able to call into the `F2()` etc of Foo class. You can achieve this by passing an additional `IFoo` as an argument to their `f()` functions.

```
struct F1Policy {
   virtual void f(IFoo * foo)=0;
};

struct DefaultF1Policy : public F1Policy {
   void f(IFoo * foo) override {
      foo->F2();
   }
}; 

void Foo::F1() { 
  f1Policy->f(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the clients implement the delegation themselves you could provide a different base class for your clients to inherit from, which by default forwards the call to the appropriate implementation. That way, your clients only have to override the functions they need. Have a look below

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// expose this to your clients
struct interface {

    virtual void f1() = 0;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
    virtual void f3() = 0;

    virtual ~interface() = default;

};

// this is your default implementation
struct default_implementation
: public interface {

    void f1() override {std::cout << "default f1" << std::endl;}
    void f2() override {std::cout << "default f2" << std::endl;}
    void f3() override {std::cout << "default f3" << std::endl;}
};

// this is a way for your client to create a pointer to your default implementation
std::shared_ptr<interface> create_default_implementation() {
    return std::make_shared<default_implementation>();
}

// expose this to your clients too
// this is the class your clients will inherit from
// this essentially uses the decorator pattern and ensures that by default all f1, f2, f3 delegate to the appropriate implementation
class client_base
: public interface {

    std::shared_ptr<interface> m_impl;

public:

    client_base(std::shared_ptr<interface> default_impl = create_default_implementation())
    : m_impl(default_impl){}

    void f1() override {
        m_impl->f1();
    }

    void f2() override {
        m_impl->f2();
    }

    void f3() override {
        m_impl->f3();
    }
};

// now your clients can override whichever functions they feel like
class client_foo1
: public client_base {

public:
    using client_base::client_base;

    void f1() override {std::cout << "foo1 f1" << std::endl;}
    void f11() {/* put whatever here */ }
};


class client_foo2
: public client_base {

public:
    using client_base::client_base;

    void f2() override {std::cout << "foo2 f2" << std::endl;}
    void f12() {/* put whatever here */ }
};

int main() {

    client_foo1 foo1;
    client_foo2 foo2;

    foo1.f1(); // prints foo1 f1
    foo1.f2(); // prints default f2
    foo1.f3(); // prints default f3

    foo2.f1(); // prints default f1
    foo2.f2(); // prints foo2 f2
    foo2.f3(); // prints default f3

}
```